# How to move a polygon (or any other none basic shape) in svg.js?

Tags: svg.js

Let's assume I have created two SVG elements: rect and polygon.
I can simply move the rect around via rect.move(x, y) or rect.dmove(x, y)

**What is the best way to move the polygon?**

Do I have to create a group first? Seems like an overhead for me...

.move() is not working (I guess because it messes with the points attribute?!)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `polygon.move(0,0)` is working quite fine. So there is no need for anything fancy. However if you do not want to mess with the point attributes, you can use `polygon.translate(x, y)` which will add a transformation to the element which moves the element by the amount specified in `translate`